# Razor view escape @ sign in regular expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, escaping

IN MVC Razor view i am writing a regular expression to detect URL in text. 
Expression is

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
```

But MVC is showing error on each @ sign , how can i escape to avoid error ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `@@` to escape `@`

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
```

The html output will contain single `@`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
</script>
```